# I do not know what to do next in my Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I was trying to create a python dictionary out of this problem and yet I do not know what to do next, please guide me guys

Convert the table into a Python Dictionary.

```
NAME | SALARY
--------------------­--------
John | 8000
Marie | 7500
David | 9500
Winston | 10000
Victor | 7000
```

Then display the name of the next person with higher salary. If there is no one, display -1

Output:

```
John - David
Marie - David
David - Winston
Winston - -1
Victor - -1
```

## your solution goes here

```python
Name = { "John" : 8000, "Marie" : 7500, "David" : 9500, "Winston": 10000, "Victor": 7000 }
```

Comment: sorry guys i am just self-learning

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is working and what not?